# Await results of several different asynchronous operations using Task.WhenAny

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I've been searching for a solution for a while now to what seems like it *must* be a simple problem. However, every example that I find creates a collection of `Task`s similar to this one (taken from the [How to: Extend the Async Walkthrough by Using Task.WhenAll (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh556530.aspx) page on MSDN):

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery = 
    from url in urlList select ProcessURLAsync(url);
```

I am unable to do this as I want to call different `async` methods and `await` the results... something more like this (but not this because this doesn't seem to do anything):

```
var getTicketTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<ITicket>>>();
getTicketTasks.Add(new Task(() => Model.GetTicketsAsync(eventDate)));
getTicketTasks.Add(new Task(() => Model.GetGuestTicketsAsync(eventDate)));
...
getTicketTasks.Add(new Task(() => Model.GetOtherTicketsAsync(eventDate)));

IEnumerable<ITicket>[] tickets = await Task.WhenAll(getTicketTasks);
```

So how can I call a number of `async` methods and `await` the results using the [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) method?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetTicketsAsync`, `GetGuestTicketsAsync` ..?

Comment: `Task<IEnumerable<TicketVendor>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use that task constructor to call an asynchronous method*. Simply call these methods, store the returned tasks and `await` all of them together with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var getTicketTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<ITicket>>>();
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetTicketsAsync(eventDate));
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetGuestTicketsAsync(eventDate));
...
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetOtherTicketsAsync(eventDate));

IEnumerable<ITicket>[] tickets = await Task.WhenAll(getTicketTasks);
```

In your case you create a task, but you don't start it so it doesn't run. If you did start it you would simply fire your actual asynchronous operations without storing the returned task anywhere. That means that you have nothing to `await`. All the tasks you are awaiting do is fire and forget another `async` operation.

`Task.WhenAll` also has an overload with `params` so another option would be:

```
var tickets = await Task.WhenAll(
    Model.GetTicketsAsync(eventDate),
    Model.GetGuestTicketsAsync(eventDate),
    Model.GetOtherTicketsAsync(eventDate));
```

---

<sup>* Or in any other case for that matter.</sup>

Comment: +1 Thanks for responding so quickly... although I have to admit that it was a real pain trying to read your reply while you were still updating it every few seconds... I'd personally prefer to wait a little longer and read it all in one go, but then perhaps I should have returned later? Either way, your solution appears to work, so thanks.

Comment: @Sheridan Do whatever works for you. You can read everything hours later as long as you're responding to clarification questions people may have.

Answer (score 2):

You've just created the `Task`. You never started it. Creating a `Task` via its constructor will not start the `Task` and hence will not transform to completed state either. So awaiting it will take forever.

Use `Task.Run` or call `Task.Start` however calling `Task.Start` isn't recommended. Prefer `Task.Run` to start a asynchronous operation.  If you already have `Task<T>` simply create a array and await it.

```
var getTicketTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<ITicket>>>();
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetTicketsAsync(eventDate));
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetGuestTicketsAsync(eventDate));
...
getTicketTasks.Add(Model.GetOtherTicketsAsync(eventDate));
IEnumerable<ITicket>[] tickets = await Task.WhenAll(getTicketTasks);
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `Task.Run` in this case.

Comment: @I3arnon I thought OP is having synchronous method despite of the name `Async`. Later after confirming it is `Task<T>` I updated my answer and removed `Task.Run` in code.

Comment: +1 Yep, that was my bad... I answered his question incorrectly - sorry.

Comment: Also, thanks for your response @SriramSakthivel... where were my manners a minute ago?